# Get formatted output of file details in a folder

Tags: windows, powershell

I want to retrieve certain details about all files in a given folder.

```
Get-ItemPropertyValue .\*.dll -name versioninfo
```

Gives me output like this:

[image: psoutput]

That aint bad but i wanna include some other properties, and the -include switch doesnt work like i thought.

And giving it -name versioninfo, lastwritetime for example, doesnt add another column to the list, it prints the date underneath:

[image: wrong formatted output]

How can i bring all read properties of one file into the same row (add column)?

EDIT:
i am aware of format-list but its not giving me the wide list output and format-wide only accepts one single property...

Comment: I qould strongly recommend to use code blocks instead of screenshots. They are searchable, editable, copyable and more readable (especially looking at your transparency, which makes it harder to focus)

Comment: It makes it also easier for you to censor output. Without wanting to critic your paint skills, I'm sure it's easy to reproduce what's under the red lines.

Comment: yeah i dont have the patience to reformat the code in this shitty editor, it gets totally shredded. and they have the pic function for a reason but thanks for your concerns, it will be considered next time.

Comment: There is nothing "shitty" about the editor. If I just copy & paste PowerShell outputs into code blocks, everything works fine. If you have problems formatting your question, take a look at the help center. Here is a great resource on this: [Screenshots of code & Errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: thanks for all your considerations. i will think about using the blocks next time. any further comments about this is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
Get-Item .\*.dll | Select-Object `
 @{N='ProductVersion';E={Get-ItemPropertyValue $_ -Name versionInfo | Select-Object -ExpandProperty ProductVersion}} `
,@{N='FileVersion';E={Get-ItemPropertyValue $_ -Name versionInfo | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FileVersion}} `
,Name `
,LastWriteTime
```

Comment: brilliant!
it ended up working for me like this `Get-Item *.dll | Select-Object (@{N='ProductVersion';E={Get-ItemPropertyValue $_ -Name versionInfo | Select-Object -ExpandProperty ProductVersion}}),(@{N='FileVersion';E={Get-ItemPropertyValue $_ -Name versionInfo | Select-O
bject -ExpandProperty FileVersion}}),Name,LastWriteTime`

Comment: do you have an idea why this wouldn't work inside a script but does so if executed in the console by itself?

Answer (score 0):

I found an easier, more readable way to do this, and still generate the output when run inside a script:

```
Get-Childitem .\ThirdPartyComponents\*.dll | select name, lastwritetime, @{l="ProductVersion";e={$_.VersionInfo.ProductVersion}}, @{l="FileVersion";e={$_.VersionInfo.FileVersion}} | ft
```

The last pipe to `| ft` (Format table) is needed because the command does not generate any output when run inside a script otherwise. Why that is, im not exactly sure..